# how to access a method in a model from a controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to put logic in the model rather than controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def somemethod
    d = User.methodinmodel
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def methodinmodel
    "retuns foo"
  end
end
```

I get an error that there is no `methodinmodel` for the `User` model.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to call `methodinmodel` on the `User` class in general rather than a specific user, you need to make it a class method using `self`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.methodinmodel
    "returns foo"
  end
end
```

Your current method definition would only work if you called it on a user:

```
@user = User.create!
@user.methodinmodel  # Works.
User.methodinmodel   # Doesn't work.
```

Using the new implementation using `self` would allow you to call it like:

```
User.methodinmodel   # Works.
```